# Constructor <Beginner>

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, while studying about the constructor, I was trying a code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CCircle
{
    double dRadius;
public:
    CCircle(double in_Radius) : dRadius(in_Radius) {}

    double area()
    {
        return (3.14*dRadius*dRadius);
    }
};


class CCylinder
{
    CCircle CircleObject;
    double dheight;

public:
    CCylinder(double in_dheight) : dheight(in_dheight) {}

    double volume()
    {
        return (CircleObject.area()*dheight);
    }
};

int main()
{
    CCircle CircleObject (0.5);
    CCylinder CylinderObject (5.2);
    cout<<"Area is " << CircleObject.area() <<endl;
    cout<<"Volume is " << CylinderObject.volume() <<endl;
}
```

Have I made any mistakes in this code? If yes can you let me know the mistake?? I could not able to trace it out the problem

Comment: `CCircle` doesn't have default constructor, you have to specify `in_Radius` to initialize `CircleObject` in `CCylinder`.

Comment: What makes you think you have a mistake?  Did you get an error?  If so, what was it?

Comment: I hope you are not just writing code without trying to compile it from time to time, so you already know that there is a mistake in your code. Please include the error message you get in the question

Comment: Please make your title describe the question.

Comment: Ask youself in this code `CCylinder CylinderObject (5.2);` what is the radius of your cylinder? Hopefully this will make you understand what you did wrong.

Comment: I suspect that you believe that there is some connection between the `CircleObject` variable in `main` and the `CircleObject` member of  `CCylinder`. There isn't.

Comment: I'd love to have a robust conversation with the chap who decided that all classes should start with a 'C'.

Comment: I suggest you read up on Hungarian Notation if you wish to be more consistent.  Also, what happens when a variable's type changes?  I would expect that the variable name would have to be modified (I don't see this happening very often, so basically Hungarian Notation leads to lies and can't be trusted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking if there are any problems, while your program does not even compile. You should get this error:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘CCylinder::CCylinder(double)’:
main.cpp:29:52: error: no matching function for call to 
    ‘CCircle::CCircle()’
   CCylinder(double in_dheight) : dheight(in_dheight) {}
```

which mentions that Circle class has no default constructor. That means that you should pass the parameter to the constructor (in_Radius).

Or, of course, you could just provide a default constructor for circle, or even a default value for the parameter of the already existing circle constructor.

Comment: Can we declare CCircle CircleObject (0.6); inside class CCylinder.??

Comment: After adding the default constructor it is working. This question might be even silly what is the role of default constructor?

Comment: @satiz01bravo good. You can read about the purpose of the default constructor here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-default-constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working as the error clearly says no default constructor is defined `error: no matching function for call to ‘CCircle::CCircle()’`

Try this

```
class CCircle
{
    double dRadius;
    public:
        CCircle() {}
        CCircle(double in_Radius) : dRadius(in_Radius) {}

        double area()
        {
            return (3.14*dRadius*dRadius);
        }
};


class CCylinder
    {
        CCircle CircleObject;
        double dheight;

        public:
        CCylinder() {}
        CCylinder(double in_dheight) : dheight(in_dheight) {}

        double volume()
        {
            return (CircleObject.area()*dheight);
        }
};
```